# Which distance metric to use for binary values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, math, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have 100 users who like/dislike 500 items. 
So, I have transformed the matrix with binary values, that is , if the user u1 likes an item I1, then the value is 1 and if he doesn't like the item, then the value is 0.

The matrix looks like this:

[image]

So, now I need to cluster similar users who have liked similar items. I have used K-modes clustering to cluster them but my silhouette score is very low. I am not sure which distance metric I should use. 
Euclidean distance is not a good measure for this problem. Jaccard distance is also not efficient if my dataset is large. Which other distance metric should I use in order to decrease the cost of a model.

Comment: Strictily answering the question, i suggest `cosine` or `hamming`distance. But before that may I ask how did you build this matrix ? Usually inplace of binary values you have real numbers and you get these numbers by calculating similarity score between an 'item' and a 'user'.

Comment: I guess https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58706/distance-metrics-for-binary-vectors is related, and the answers there can be used here?

Comment: @SiddhantTandon I have used both cosine and hamming. The values are still bad. I am not sure how to improve my silhouette score. 
To build the matrix, I have used dataset.pivot_table() function. And, I have used preprocessing.LabelEncoder() and applied it  on the pivot_table.

Below is the code snippet if you are interested. 
`pivot_table = dataset.pivot_table(values='Checked', index='USERID', columns = 'ITEMID').fillna(0);

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder();
pivot_table = pivot_table.apply(le.fit_transform)`

Comment: @PH so you just had the information `yes` if user likes the item and `no`if doesnt. And there is no other information on `items`? Usually you have to construct `item`profiles using `tf-idf`stuff if you have some text to work with.

Comment: @SiddhantTandon. No, there is no information on items. Only itemID and itemName are present. I don't need to know more about items because I am clustering the users who like similar items. So, only the information "like/dislike" is enough to cluster them !

Also, there is no text to work with! It is easy to integrate the itemID with its itemDescription. But, I don't need to know that. Therefore I have removed it from the dataframe.

Comment: @PH there is another approach you can try. You might want to refine your Utility matrix by first clustering the items together using `jaccard` or `cosine` and leave num clusters as half of num items. Then you can construct a new utility matrix where the entry of a user `U`and cluster `C` is the average of ratings given to the items in that cluster by the user `U`(in your case 1 ). This way you have a refined matrix with real values. You might want to read [mmds book](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch9.pdf) for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using 'Hamming distance' for finding the distance. Refer the documentation for [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.hamming.html) for method implemented in scipy library.

Comment: Thank you. But again, somehow this is not improving the silhouette score. If we use the correct distance metric, the model will work the best, that it is forms correct clusters.

Comment: Also, computing this for 10000 users can take a lot of time.

Comment: Hamming is he cheapest possible metric. Even simpler than Euclidean distance. On binary data, it's just the `XOR` and `POPCNT` instructions that each execute in a single clock cycle...

Comment: But if your data is stored as integer vectors containing only 0 and 1s, Euclidean distance is pretty much the same, precisely sqrt(Hamming).

Comment: @HasQUIT--Anony-Mousse But Euclidean distance is giving me a lesser score and has no improvements. When you mentioned in the answer that "decomposing the matrix into n x k and k x m matrixes that map users to factors and factors to likes." , can I just run K-modes on the user matrix, n x k matrix to find the similar users?

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach with such data would be to use nonnegative matrix factorization (NMF). Roughly, this means decomposing the matrix into n x k and k x m matrixes that map users to factors and factors to likes.

Comment: Thank you. I also read about it. But, I am not sure how to proceed further with my problem. I need to cluster similar users who like similar items. So, this data is represented in Binary matrix. Now, I am not sure what I can do with decomposing the matrix into n x k and k x m matrices because this helps in recommendation. But, what about clustering?